# Android studio emulator issue- Glitches

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

[image]

There is some glitches on android studio emulator. Is this hardware issue or software. Can anyone tell the solutions. Thank you

Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-10300H CPU @ 2.50GHz   2.50 GHz
Installed RAM   16.0 GB (15.8 GB usable)
System type 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor

Answer (score 0):

It is a software problem.
It can be because the Android Studio emulator have an high usage of the CPU(processor).
The cause of the constant using of the CPU can be the audio and/or GPS that is used by the emulator.
To disable audio in the emulator ,add/change this lines in the emulator configuration file to this:

```
hw.audioInput=no
hw.audioOutput=no
```

To disable GPS in the emulator ,add/change this lines in the emulator configuration file to this:

```
hw.GPS = no
```

On Linux/Mac the file is located at ~/.android/avd/<AVD_Name>.avd/config.ini
On Windows the file is located at C:\Users<username>.android\avd<AVD_Name>.avd\config.ini